# CakePHP Shopping cart plugin

Tags: cakephp

Can someone suggest a good CakePHP shopping cart plugin? I am building an e-business website that requires a shopping cart to save all the products that customers want to purchase, and use PayPal to execute the payment. All the plugins I found online are kinda outdated.
Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I am developing shopping cart plugin and will release it very soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's for 2.0 https://github.com/burzum/Cart but I haven't had the time and mood to add a Paypal adapter yet because I just needed another provider for myself so far. But should be easy to add.